# Problema con compilación de proyecto desarrollado en 3 capas

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-server-2016

Este es mi primer post o consulta, así que no sean muy duros conmigo. Estoy realizando un proyecto en 3 capas: Capa Datos, Capa Negocio, Capa Presentación, bueno el hecho está en que cuando le doy a compilar a toda la solución, me sale el siguiente mensaje:

[image: Errores del compilador de VS Studio]

Estoy usando C# como lenguaje de programación. Si alguien puede brindarme ayuda sería bueno, tal vez es un asunto muy obvio. De todas formas gracias y que tengan buen día. PD: supuestamente no se encuentran esos archivos, en todo caso, cómo los genero?

Comment: Creaste las referencias en cada proyecto? es decir un proyecto depende de otro si es en capa, haz creado las referencias entre ellos?

Comment: Sí, eso ya realicé, he revisado todo el código, se pressentaban errores menores, pero eso que mencionas es lo primero que se realiza al crear las capas.

Comment: Casi no se puede leer los errores, pero veo que el  principal problema es que el programa no cuenta con un método `Main` para iniciar correctamente, los demás errores hacen referencias a archivos nos encontrados, prueba hacer `Clean` y `Rebuild` a la solución de tu proyecto a ver que te dice.

Comment: define tu proyecto de la capa de presentación como el proyecto de inicio

Comment: la capa de presentacion  que tipo de proyecto es?

Comment: La capa de presentación es un winform, haré eso freddy, probaré que tal sale...

Comment: Tu error esta en que no tienes definido el metodo Main en la clase Program.

Answer (score 1):

Existe varías soluciones para dicho problema, la cual te proporcionaré algunas de ellas:

1. Debes darle click derecho a cada proyecto y posteriormente dar click a la opción Limpiar y luego dar click a la opción de compilar por cada proyecto (Uno por uno), en el orden de la dependencias, es decir, si tu capa de negocios depende de la capas de datos, debe compilar primero la capa de datos y posteriormente la de negocio, tal como se muestra en la siguiente imágenes:

**Imagen 1.** Opciones de limpiar y compilar (Visual Studio 2017)
[image: Opción de limpiar y compilar]

**Imagen 2.** Ejemplo de diagrama de dependencias de proyecto

[image: Ejemplo de dependencia de proyectos]

2. Otra opción es darle click derecho en el proyecto, posteriormente seleccionar la opción, Dependencia de compilación, y nuevamente Dependencia de compilación, y posteriormente seleccionar los proyectos dependientes, tal como se muestra en la imágenes:

**Imagen 3.** Opción de dependencias de proyectos (Visual Studio 2017)
[image: Opciones de dependencias de proyectos]

**Imagen 4.** Selección de proyectos dependientes (Visual Studio 2017)
[image: Opción de dependencias de proyectos (2)]

** Observación: Si realiza dicho paso, al darle la opción de Limpiar y compilar todo, lo hará en el orden de dependencias (Lo cual te ahorrarás mucho tiempo)

Answer (score 0):

se que ya ha pasado mucho tiempo desde que se publico este problema. a mi me paso igual con vs comunity 2019. algunas soluciones que encontre fue darle click derecho al proyecto y luego limpiar, y luego compilar. no me funciono.
lo que si me funciono fue [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

selecionar aqui compilar y luego compular por lote. seleccionar todo y compilar y ahora si soy feliz, todo funciona. espero que esta solucion ayude a alguien mas.